# How to create a generic component to be reused by other components

Tags: angular, angular-components

So i have this component which is used to just show a div sliding into the page with a template another components provide

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-slide-in',
  templateUrl: './slide-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slide-in.component.less'],
  animations: [
    trigger('widthGrow', [
      state('closed', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
      state('open', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' })),
      transition('* => *', animate(250))
    ]),
  ]
})
export class SlideInComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;

  state = "closed";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  changeState(): void {
    (this.state == "closed") ? this.state = "open" : this.state = "closed";
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is from another component where I have a ng template like this

```
<button (click)="Open()">Open</button>
<ng-template #filters>
  ...
</ng-template>
```

be able to pass this template in the other component when the user clicks Open

```
export class Component2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  Open(): void {
  var slideInComp = new SlideInComponent();
  slideInComp.changeState();
  }
}
```

What is the best design for something like this ? i want to reuse this within other components, but passing in different templates

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I've understood your question entirely. If all you want to do is to create a re-usable animation, I suggest that you should use a directive for that purpose only.

If you want the `ng-template` that you have there to be displayed inside the `SlideInComponent` then you should probably be doing something like this:

```
<button (click)="Open(slideInComponentRef)">Open</button>
<app-slide-in #slideInComponentRef [template]="filters" />
<ng-template #filters>
  ...
</ng-template>
```

And in your parent component

```
export class Component2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  Open(slideInComponentRef: SlideInComponent): void {
  slideInComponentRef.changeState();
  }
}
```

Or, an even better approach would be to make use of `<ng-content>` in your `SlideInComponent` and have the template something like this:

```
<div>
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

and then you won't need the `@Input() template` anymore and you can use it like

```
<app-slide-in #slideInComponentRef>
....
html template code goes here
....
</app-slide-in>
```